# Qt show() executed after function

Tags: c++, qt, show

I would like to show a label and execute a function **after** displaying the label. Unfortunately, the label is always displayed after the function is executed.

```
void MainWindow::showLabel(){
    myLabel->show();
    doSomething();
}

void MainWindow::doSomething(){
    QThread::msleep(3000);
    myLabel->hide();
}
```

So, when i execute my code, the programm waits for three seconds and does show me an empty window afterwards (since it directly hides the label before even showing it; if I comment the hide function, the label is shown after waiting three seconds).
What I've tried to do is modifying the showEvent like this:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event) {
    QMainWindow::showEvent(event);
    doSomething();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong by modifying the method or is there any other way to show the label before executing the followed function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve your problem in the following way:

```
void MainWindow::showLabel()
{
    myLabel->show();
    // Wait for 3sec. and hide the label.
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, myLabel, SLOT(hide()));;
}
```

i.e. you don't need the second function and to block the current thread with `QThread::msleep()`, which is the reason why your label appears after the timeout is fired.

**Update**

If you need to do more than just hiding a label, define a slot and call it like:

```
void MainWindow::showLabel()
{
    myLabel->show();
    // Wait for 3sec. and call a slot.
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(doSomething()));
}

// This is a slot
void MainWindow::doSomething()
{
    myLabel->hide();
    [..]
    // some more stuff
}
```

Comment: What do I do in case that I want to add some more code to the doSomething()?

Comment: Please don't use the Qt4-style syntax. Use the much safer one: `QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, &MainWindow::doSomething));` It doesn't even need to be a slot. Or even a function, you can use a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

*QThread::msleep(3000);* is blocking the main thread where event loop is processed. So it prevent to show *myLabel* until sleep time is end. The solution is either to use QTimer as vahancho recomended or call event loop processing manualy by calling *QEventLoop::exec()*  after  *myLabel->show();*.